# How can the 'OK' button in a popup box be selected during automation in Mocha Selenium framework

Tags: selenium, automation, mocha.js

I am trying to get the 'OK' button of a popup to be clicked. The popup comes from a menu item selected on the screen. When inspecting the popup in chrome, there isn't any elementid that I can use.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some pointers as I cannot find topics about this online, I couldn't find any documentation about this and I'm really new to using the Mocha Selenium framework for automation.

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsFqB.png)

Comment: Please provide a link to the page you are working with or at lest HTML code of that page. We have nothing to do with your picture.

Answer (score 0):

You want to close an alert box, this should work:

```
await driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

or to dismiss the box:

```
await driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```